# Ubuntu server 16.04.03 goes to sleep on esx

Tags: server, suspend, vmware, lts, esx

My freshly installed Ubuntu server on version 16.04.03 goes to sleep after some time, I believe when I log out of the webserver.

I tried already many answers to questions I have found on this website but none of them seem to work or I do not have them, I do not have GNOME.

Already did the relevant commands on this: [How to disable all power management in Ubuntu for a server netbook](https://serverfault.com/questions/321499/how-to-disable-all-power-management-in-ubuntu-for-a-server-netbook).

So I'm thinking it must be this version specific.

Answer (score 1):

Do you try by adding `acpi=off` and `apm=off` to the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub`?

Then run `sudo update-grub` and reboot your server.

Comment: thanks i saw it but i am not sure exactly, with or without quiet splash?

Comment: without quiet splash

Comment: and then, just after typing the post it went to sleep again...  :(

Comment: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off apm=off"
 like this?

Comment: Try this `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi=off apm power_off=1"`. After this run `sudo update-grub` and reboot server.

Comment: When you say "server go to sleep", you got black screen but services working or service do not work?

Comment: server becomes totally unresponsive (every service), i have to go to the esx, power off, power on.

Comment: Check `power options` in VMware for that vm

Comment: i found something in the log, investigating: 
The CPU has been disabled by the guest operating system. Power off or reset the virtual machine.

Comment: plus when the hosts hangs, it is telling me vmware tools are not running anymore